# Are Romulans related to Xenomorphs?

Tags: star-trek, alien-franchise, alien-1979, xenomorph, star-trek-picard

In the first episode of *Star Trek: Picard* the character Dahj is attacked for a second time. During the fight it is revealed that the attackers are Romulan. Dahj fights off all the attackers, but one of them, obviously wounded, spits a green substance on Dahj and a gun she is holding. The green substance appears to be blood. It  burns into Dahj's skin and also causes a (plasma?) gun she is holding to explode, killing her.

The only other green substance I know of that corrodes materials like that is the blood of the Xenomorphs from the *Alien* universe. Is there a connection? Coincidence? In this day and age?

I know Romulans are related to the Vulcan people. What color is their blood.

And if it was not blood but some type of bio-weapon, how could the Romulan attacker spit it without himself getting wounded?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the Star Trek universe(s) is/are full enough that they don't have to cross over into the Alien franchise.

Comment: Vulcans have green blood because it's copper based ([source](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Vulcan#Physiology)) instead of a human's iron based red blood. Since Romulans come from the same evolutionary branch, their blood should be copper based as well ([source](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Romulan#Physiology)).

Comment: @Jeeped there has been a [Star Trek / X-Men](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek/X-Men) crossover - so I wouldn't rule anything out

Comment: In resonse to your 4th question, at least one [source](https://www.trekbbs.com/threads/acid-spitting.302805/) has looked at the frame-by-frame close enough that *'If you watch the scene, however, you can see that the acid actually reacts with his own skin just as his target.'*.

Comment: No, Romulans are evolved ant-lion workers.  Star Trek is in the Half-Life universe.  The Computer is GlaDOS evolved.  Or to be more precise, the entire experience of 24th century humans is a simulation to occupy their higher brains.  Their lower brains are testing.  For Science.

Comment: @HorusKol And [two](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek/Green_Lantern) with [Green Lantern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek/Green_Lantern:_Stranger_Worlds)

Comment: The assassin bites an "Acid capsule" hidden as a fake tooth. You can see that the acid starts dissolving him before dahj corrodes. It's a last resort suicidal attack.

Answer (score 6):

## *No.*

Xenomorphs are part of a fictional universe created by [Ridley Scott and Dan O'Bannon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alien_(film)), and expanded upon by countless other authors.

Romulans are part of a fictional universe created by [Gene Roddenberry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek), and expanded upon by *many* authors, directors and screen writers.

There is no cross-over between these universes in canon.